Definition of a differential form on a formal group
I'm trying to understand Silverman's ACE 4.4 The Invariant Differential. This section begins as follows:

We return to the study of a formal group $\mathcal{F}$ defined over an arbitrary ring $R$. In a formal setting of this sort, a differential form is simply an expression $P(T)dT$ wiht $P(T)\in R[[T]]$. $\cdots$

At first time, i interpreted differential forms as elements of module $(\Omega_{R[[T]]/R},d)$ of Kahler differentials of $R[[T]]$ over $R$. But if $f\in R[[T]]$ is not a polynomial, we have to do addition infinitely many times to verity the equality $df=f'dT$, so it seems incorrect.
In this post, Adam give a definition, he defined a space of formal differential form as a quotient module.
Where does this definition come from? I can't find it in the lecture note he attached.
What is the definition of differential forms of a formal group $\mathcal{F}/R$?
